# How can I add more 3th DLL function references in .rdata section of EXE program?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

I'm working on extending the old WinAPI program (I don't have source code - only EXE) with the possibility to write debug messages on standard output. That program already uses kernel32.dll library and in the .rdata section I see a lot of references to different functions in 3th part DLLs. In order to do that I need `WriteConsole` function which lives in kernel32.dll. I used the simplest strategy and just copied the memory address of `WriteConsole` in kernel32.dll in time of debugger breakpoint. After restart of program, I was disappointed that the address doesn't point anymore into kernel32.dll `WriteConsole`. Instead, it pointed into another random DLL.

I wonder what is recommended and easiest option to setup properly address to that external function?

I sow that x32dgb have a section with symbols - can I use some x32dbg feature to add other functions pointers from existing DLLs?
[image]

Thank you :-)

Comment: Aside: Out of curiosity, since you don't have the source code, how did you plan to add a call to WriteConsole(W) to the program after having successfully added that function to the IAT?

Comment: Why do you need to resolve those imports at load time? Indeed, why does the target application need to import your logging functions at all? Just use your own module that imports `WriteConsole` et. al. and patch the executable to call into your module. If you are lucky, the target application was compiled with the [/hotpatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/hotpatch-create-hotpatchable-image) compiler option, providing you a safe point to install your hooks.

Comment: @IInspectable: If you're modifying the executable on disk, you don't even need `/hotpatch`.  You can just take any function that's more than 5 bytes of machine code and replace the first 1 or more instructions with a `jmp rel32` to somewhere.  Or if you're patching on the fly, you still don't need `/hotpatch` if no other threads have been started which might have a program-counter pointing into the middle of the 5-byte `jmp` instruction you're about to write.  (You can figure out if you need to copy the instructions you overwrote into your jump target so they still happen.)

Comment: I don't want to resolve that import at load time. I want to patch exe to load that missing functions on start together with other kernel32.dll functions. How to do that?

Comment: That **is** called [load-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking). @pet Sure, `/hotpatch` isn't strictly required, though it makes patching the executable in memory much more reliable. You can certainly patch the executable image on disk, though games in particular will verify the authenticity of modules.

Comment: @IInspectable: more reliable how?  If you have room in an executable page somewhere else in its address space, and you can do your patching while no other threads are running, there's no reason you'd need anything special at the start of a function you're hooking.  It might mean you need to decode to find how many instruction bytes to copy to get the full instructions that were overlapped by a 5-byte `jmp rel32`, and where to jump back to the original if you don't fully replace / duplicate it.

Comment: @IInspectable: I was mostly talking about a specific case where a human can look at the original binary (because in the OP's case it's *not* going to change to a new version), and design the code they want at the hooked version.  (Because otherwise, I guess a `jcc rel8` in the first 5 bytes might need to turn into a jcc rel32 to reach back to the original, so the possible complexity could be high, especially if the top of a loop is within those first 5 bytes so later code in the function has to be adjusted, too).

Comment: @pet *"you can do your patching while no other threads are running"* - That's not enough. Consider a thread you suspended while it was executing the instructions you are replacing with the new instruction boundaries no longer matching those you replaced (and the suspended thread already started decoding).

Comment: @IInspectable: I meant while no other threads *exist*, as I said in my first comment. e.g. if you hook (with an external debugger?) early enough in process startup that there's still only the main thread.  Then you're still avoiding the need for truly *hot* patching.  Otherwise yes, you would need to find a 2-byte instruction (and some nearby padding to put a jmp rel32) near the start of a function, or a >= 5-byte insn.  (And use `xchg` to atomically modify a 2-byte insn if it misaligned, or `lock cmpxchg8b` to atomically modify an 8-byte chunk including the 5 byte jmp)

Comment: Hm, can you send me out some link to tutorial how to extend IAT for existing EXE? I tried to use https://github.com/secana/PeNet but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show how to add `WriteConsoleA` entry to IAT. This is the ANSI version of `WriteConsole`, when you need to output UNICODE strings, use `WriteConsoleW`. From your screenshot I see that currently your binary uses ANSI versions of `kernel32.dll` functions, for example `GetStartupInfoA`.

Download PETools. Run it, select `Tools->Pe Editor` and select your binary. A dialog box appears. Click `Directories` button, a new dialog box appears. Click `...` button for import directory. Import directory window opens. Right click on a dll in the upper list, select `Add Imports...`.
Enter `KERNEL32.dll` as dll name, `WriteConsoleA` in the API name edit, click `+` button. Click OK. Close all the windows and save changes by
clicking close, save and OK buttons. Your binary will have a new entry in IAT for `WriteConsoleA` function.